# Trigger periodic job in Hudson only if last execution of another job is successful

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I have a job `NIGHTLY` that runs one time each night by a periodical timer.
Now I want to change so that the `NIGHTLY` job is only run if the last execution of another job `FOO` in Hudson is successful.

Note:

- Job `FOO` is run many times each day and is triggered by SCM.
- `NIGHTLY` should only be run one time per night and at a specific time.

Currently I have another job `NIGHTLY_TRIGGER` that runs a bash script that access the remote API of job `FOO` to check if job `FOO` is successful and if so triggers the NIGHTLY job.

Are there a nicer/cleaner way to do this? (preferable by using some Hudson plugins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check out the **[Hudson Join Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin)** which is made for this kind of scenario (wait for the conclusion of a job before executing another one).
The end result wouldn't be much different from what you are already doing, but this would be neatly parameterized:

[image]

So you would still have to check the status of `FOO` job, but at least you would check it *right after* `FOO` job completion.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this would solve the problem. I want the NIGHTLY job to be run only once at a certain time each night triggered by a periodical timer and that the periodical timer would be blocked/canceled if the FOO job is not successful. Although it looks like a nice plugin =)

Comment: @ki_: could you make that periodical timer as a trigger for FOO? : if FOO fails ("unstable"), the timer won't run.

Comment: What do you mean with that the "periodical timer" should be a trigger for FOO? I don't want to schedule FOO to run every night.

Comment: @ki_: right, I understand better now. And I am not sure there is a better way than controlling your NIGHTLY_BUILD job execution through the remote API.